# Issues with special characters from IBM DB2 to SQL in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, db2

I am trying to pull data from IBM db2 into a SQL table via SSIS.

However, the table (source) contains a special character in the column, like below;

`"?Çª. note pads wearing thin"`

As a result, my package fails with the following error;

> [OLE DB Source [33]] Error: There was an error with OLE DB
> Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[VTTEXT] on OLE DB
> Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output]. The column status returned was:
> "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the
> target code page.".

The data is being loaded into a VARCHAR column within SQL, but the error seems specific to my data source.

How can I get around it?

Comment: Try to change the VARCHAR column to NVARCHAR

Comment: Look at the data definition in DB2. `SELECT * FROM ABC01.sysibm.systables AS X WHERE X.TBNAME = 'MyTable'` That will pull back the metadata that defines your table. What is the data type, COLTYPE, for NAME = 'VTTEXT' You'll also want to identify the LENGTH property to ensure you have a match between the length in DB2 vs SQL Server. Given the column name, I expect this will be a large object type. Finally, inspect the data in DB2 in a mainframe/as400 screen. Does it show the same as what you pasted into the question? There might be codepage issues at play here as well. Is  DB2 on zOS or LUW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an nvarchar column can store any Unicode data the varchar column is restricted to an 8-bit codepage. Codepage incompatabilities are frequent issues, so `Unicode` is the cure for codepage problems.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
MODIFY thecolumn NVARCHAR(255);
```

Comment: I amended the destination column to NVARCHAR, but still received an error from the OLE DB source. Therefore had to convert the DB2 query too; CAST(VTTEXT AS NVARCHAR(120)) AS VTTEXT